failed pipeline integration with SonarQube
I have a pipeline where Gradle@3 always fails due to some failed tasks. I have added continueOnError.
I'm wondering if there is someway to make the pipeline always marked as succeeded so that it can be later on integrated with SonarQube since I have bee told that SonarQube only accepts succeeded pipelines.
How to do that? is it a good idea? And how is it going to affect the result?
- task: Gradle@3
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/gradlew'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
    tasks: 'build --continue'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17' # Use pre-installed JAVA17
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    spotBugsAnalysis: false

Thus here are fail logs
FAILURE: Build completed with 14 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':libraries:mediaupload:impl:testDebugUnitTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/user/myagent/_work/11/s/libraries/mediaupload/impl/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/index.html

* Try:
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintGplayDebug'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.
  
  Fix the issues identified by lint, or create a baseline to see only new errors.
  To create a baseline, run `gradlew updateLintBaseline` after adding the following to the module's build.gradle file:
  ``
  android {
      lint {
          baseline = file("lint-baseline.xml")
      }
  }
  ``
  For more details, see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#snapshot
  
  Lint found 1 errors, 195 warnings. First failure:
  
  /home/user/myagent/_work/11/s/features/messages/impl: Error: Unexpected failure during lint analysis (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
  
  
  The full lint text report is located at:
    /home/user/myagent/_work/11/s/app/build/intermediates/lint_intermediate_text_report/gplayDebug/lintReportGplayDebug/lint-results-gplayDebug.txt

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tests:uitests:lintDebug'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.
  
  Fix the issues identified by lint, or create a baseline to see only new errors.
  To create a baseline, run `gradlew updateLintBaseline` after adding the following to the module's build.gradle file:
  ``
  android {
      lint {
          baseline = file("lint-baseline.xml")
      }
  }
  ``
  For more details, see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#snapshot
  
  Lint found 1 errors, 193 warnings. First failure:
  
  /home/user/myagent/_work/11/s/features/messages/impl: Error: Unexpected failure during lint analysis (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
  
  
  The full lint text report is located at:
    /home/user/myagent/_work/11/s/tests/uitests/build/intermediates/lint_intermediate_text_report/debug/lintReportDebug/lint-results-debug.txt

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tests:uitests:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR: /home/user/myagent/_work/11/s/tests/uitests/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/release/processReleaseManifest/aapt/AndroidManifest.xml:2: AAPT: error: attribute 'package' in  tag is not a valid Android package name: 'ui'.
         

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':features:messages:impl:lintDebug'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.
  
  Fix the issues identified by lint, or create a baseline to see only new errors.
  To create a baseline, run `gradlew updateLintBaseline` after adding the following to the module's build.gradle file:
  ``
  android {
      lint {
          baseline = file("lint-baseline.xml")
      }
  }
  ``
  For more details, see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#snapshot
  
  Lint found 1 errors, 90 warnings. First failure:
  
  /home/user/myagent/_work/11/s/features/messages/impl: Error: Unexpected failure during lint analysis (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
  
  
  The full lint text report is located at:
    /home/user/myagent/_work/11/s/features/messages/impl/build/intermediates/lint_intermediate_text_report/debug/lintReportDebug/lint-results-debug.txt

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyFdroidNightlyWithR8'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
   > Compilation failed to complete

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':features:roomdirectory:impl:testReleaseUnitTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/user/myagent/_work/11/s/features/roomdirectory/impl/build/reports/tests/testReleaseUnitTest/index.html

* Try:
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

8: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':libraries:mediaupload:impl:testReleaseUnitTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/user/myagent/_work/11/s/libraries/mediaupload/impl/build/reports/tests/testReleaseUnitTest/index.html

* Try:
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

9: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyFdroidReleaseWithR8'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
   > Compilation failed to complete

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

10: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':libraries:session-storage:impl:verifyReleaseSessionDatabaseMigration'.
> A failure occurred while executing app.cash.sqldelight.gradle.VerifyMigrationTask$VerifyMigrationAction
   > Error migrating from 2.db, fresh database looks different from migration database:
     /tables[SessionData]/columns[SessionData.needsVerification]/defaultValue - CHANGED
       BEFORE:
         0
       AFTER:
         1
     /tables[SessionData]/definition - CHANGED
       BEFORE:
         CREATE TABLE SessionData (
             userId TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
             deviceId TEXT NOT NULL,
             accessToken TEXT NOT NULL,
             refreshToken TEXT,
             homeserverUrl TEXT NOT NULL,
             slidingSyncProxy TEXT,
             -- added in version 2
             loginTimestamp INTEGER,
             -- added in version 3
             oidcData TEXT,
             -- added in version 4
             isTokenValid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
             loginType TEXT,
             -- added in version 5
             passphrase TEXT,
             -- added in version 6
             needsVerification INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
         )
       AFTER:
         CREATE TABLE SessionData (
             userId TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
             deviceId TEXT NOT NULL,
             accessToken TEXT NOT NULL,
             refreshToken TEXT,
             homeserverUrl TEXT NOT NULL,
             slidingSyncProxy TEXT,
             loginTimestamp INTEGER
         , oidcData TEXT, isTokenValid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, loginType TEXT, passphrase TEXT, needsVerification INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1)


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

11: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':libraries:session-storage:impl:verifyDebugSessionDatabaseMigration'.
> A failure occurred while executing app.cash.sqldelight.gradle.VerifyMigrationTask$VerifyMigrationAction
   > Error migrating from 2.db, fresh database looks different from migration database:
     /tables[SessionData]/columns[SessionData.needsVerification]/defaultValue - CHANGED
       BEFORE:
         0
       AFTER:
         1
     /tables[SessionData]/definition - CHANGED
       BEFORE:
         CREATE TABLE SessionData (
             userId TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
             deviceId TEXT NOT NULL,
             accessToken TEXT NOT NULL,
             refreshToken TEXT,
             homeserverUrl TEXT NOT NULL,
             slidingSyncProxy TEXT,
             -- added in version 2
             loginTimestamp INTEGER,
             -- added in version 3
             oidcData TEXT,
             -- added in version 4
             isTokenValid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
             loginType TEXT,
             -- added in version 5
             passphrase TEXT,
             -- added in version 6
             needsVerification INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
         )
       AFTER:
         CREATE TABLE SessionData (
             userId TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
             deviceId TEXT NOT NULL,
             accessToken TEXT NOT NULL,
             refreshToken TEXT,
             homeserverUrl TEXT NOT NULL,
             slidingSyncProxy TEXT,
             loginTimestamp INTEGER
         , oidcData TEXT, isTokenValid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, loginType TEXT, passphrase TEXT, needsVerification INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1)


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

12: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
GC overhead limit exceeded

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

13: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
> GC overhead limit exceeded

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

14: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyGplayNightlyWithR8'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
   > Compilation failed to complete



I'm wondering if there is someway to make the pipeline always marked
as succeeded

If the Gradle@3task is not required, you can disable (add enabled: false) or remove it from the pipeline.
For example:
- task: Gradle@3
  enabled: false
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/gradlew'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
    tasks: 'build --continue'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17' # Use pre-installed JAVA17
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    spotBugsAnalysis: false

However, if the Gradle@3 task is required, then you have to troubleshoot and debug to make it passed. If one of the tasks fails, the pipeline will fail. No ways to make the pipeline always marked as succeeded.
It's better to clarify your problem here and share the failed log for further inspection.

if it is disabled how can i ran sonarqube and see results there?

@roteki So you need to clarify your issue and share detailed logs here so we can understand how it works and fails. Thus, we can give you corresponding troubleshoot suggestions. Otherwise, no one can help you here.

i have added fail logs to the question @Andy

@roteki It seems to be a project issue. May I know if you can build and run the tests successfully on your local machine? Have you tried the suggestions as mentioned in the logs? It's recommend troubleshooting per the logs first.
